# populating a django form dynamically with the data from the template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I have a django view as follows:

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def review(request):
    table = DummyTable(DummyModel.objects.all())        
    form = DummyForm()        
    return render(request, 'review.html', {'reviews': table, 'DummyForm': form})
```

I am passing a default `DummyForm` which is a `django-crispy-form` (although this does not matter to the issue, I think) and I need to populate it depending on the record that the user clicks on. The form itself looks as:

```
from .models import DummyModel
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field, ButtonHolder, Submit
from django.forms import ModelForm


class DummyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DummyModel
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'time_points']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DummyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-10'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('name'),
            Field('description'),
            Field('time_points'),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
            ))
```

Now, I have a javascript function that gets called when the user clicks on certain links and receives the primary key for the record that I want to render in the form. Currently, it is as follows:

```
<script>
        function EditDialog(pk) {
            // Currently doing nothing with the primary key
            // Is there a way to initialise the form with data using this key?
            $( "#dialog" ).modal({width: 500, height: 500});
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

This JS function initiates the form as:

```
<div id="dialog" class="modal" title="Edit" style="display:none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- Can I pass the primary key variable here??? -->
          {% crispy DummyForm %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

All this works fine except I have an empty form being shown on the screen. How can I bind the form to the record given by the primary key in the JS function.

usually, in the view I can do the following:

```
# As an example, just bind to the record with primary key=1
rec = DummyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).first()
form = DummyForm(model_to_dict(rec))
```

So, in a way I need to do something similar within my template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your JS, you can make an AJAX request to a Django view that will return the form populated with values.

The JS would look like:

```
<script>
    function EditDialog(pk) {
       //ajax request to retrieve the populated form
       $.ajax({
          url: '/url/to/the/view/which/returns/the/populated/form',
          method: 'GET',
          data: {
             pk: pk
          },
          success: function(formHtml){
             //place the populated form HTML in the modal body
             $('.modal-body').html(formHtml);
             $( "#dialog" ).modal({width: 500, height: 500});
          },
          dataType: 'html'
       });

       return false;
    }
</script>
```

The view that handles the AJAX request would look like:

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def populate_form(request):
   pk = request.GET.get('pk')
   rec = DummyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
   form = DummyForm(model_to_dict(rec)) 

   return render(request, 'form.html', {'DummyForm': form})
```

The `form.html` template would be a very simple template, that will not extend your base template and will only contain:

```
{% crispy DummyForm %}
```

Please note I kept the code simple, you'll have to add validation for the pk in the `populate_form` view and handle unauth AJAX calls to `populate_form` (e.g: a user who has the page opened for a long time, the session expired and the edit button is clicked)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this AJAX solution. This is a whole new world for me!